# Typesafe stack not get project template - Exception fetching from github Unexpected response code: 403

Tags: github, playframework-2.0, typesafe-stack, giter8

I'm trying typesafe stack.

Yesterday, I can get project template of typesafe stack.

```
$sudo g8 typesafehub/akka-java-maven
```

Today: I can't get project template.

```
$sudo g8 typesafehub/play-java
```

Error:

```
Exception fetching from github Unexpected response code: 403

{"message":"Missing or invalid User Agent string. See http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that github have changed their API rules.

I have seen a similar problem cited by someone using telegr.am .

I will try to have a look at how to control the user agent sent, if I get a chance today.

Only sorry to not have a complete solution for you straight away.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround:
 1.  Clone the github repo into your computer
 2. Upgrade to the latest giter8 ( see https://github.com/n8han/giter8/blob/master/notes/0.5.0.markdown)
 3. Check where the new giter8 has been installed, for me it was /home//bin/g8
 4. Execute the local template with the new giter8

`/home/<username>/bin/g8 file://home/<username>/path/to/the/template.g8`